# Error 0xC1010000 when running SSIS Package in SQL Server Agent

Tags: ssis, ssas, olap-cube, sql-server-agent

I have an SSIS package which refresh the Cube dimensions and facts. It works fine when I run this in visual studio, but getting below error when I  schedule .dtx  package in SQL server Agent.

*Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. ... Server Execute Package Utility  Version 16.0.1000.6 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft. All rights reserved.    Started:  12:33:08 pm  Error: 2023-04-12 12:33:10.34     Code: 0xC1010000     Source: Process Cube Dimensions Analysis Services Execute DDL Task     Description: The following system error occurred:  A device attached to the system is not functioning.   End Error  Error: 2023-04-12 12:33:10.34     Code: 0xC1010000     Source: Process Cube Dimensions Analysis Services Execute DDL Task     Description: The following system error occurred:  A device attached to the system is not functioning.   End Error  Error: 2023-04-12 12:33:10.34     Code: 0xC1010000     Source: Process Cube Dimensions Analysis Services Execute DDL Task     Description: The following system error occurred:  A device attached to the system is not functioning.   End Error  Error: 2023-04-12 12:33:10.34     Code: 0xC1010000     Source: Process Cube Dimensions Analysis Services Execute DDL Task     Description: The following system error occurred:  A device attached to the system is not functioning.   End Error  Error: 2023-04-12 12:33:10.34     Code: 0xC1010000     Source: Process Cube Dimensions Analysis Services Execute DDL Task     Description: The following system error occurred:  A device attached to the system is not functioning.   End Error  Error: 2023-04-12 12:33:10.34     Code: 0xC1010000     Source: Process Cube Dimensions Analysis Services Execute DDL Task     Description: The following system error occurred:  A device attached to the system is not functioning.   End Error  Error: 2023-04-12 12:33:10.34     Code: 0xC1010000     Source: Process Cube Dimensions Analysis Services Execute DDL Task     Description: The following system error occurred:  A device attached to the system is not functioning.   End Error  Error: 2023-04-12 12:33:10.34     Code: 0xC1010000     Source: Process Cube Dimensions Analysis Services Execute DDL Task     Description: The following system error occurred:  A device attached to the system is not functioning.   End Error  Error: 2023-04-12 12:33:10.34     Code: 0xC1010000     Source: Process Cube Dimensions Analysis Services Execute DDL Task     Description: The following system error occurred:  A device attached to the system is not functioning.   End Error  Error: 2023-04-12 12:33:10.34     Code: 0xC1010000     Source: Process Cube Dimensions Analysis Services Execute DDL Task     Description: The following system error occurred:  A device attached to the system is not functioning.   End Error  Error: 2023-04-12 12:33:10.34     Code: 0xC1010000     Source: Process Cube Dimensions Analysis Services Execute DDL Task     Description: The following system error occurred:  A device attached to the system is not functioning.   End Error  Error: 2023-04-12 12:33:10.34     Code: 0xC1010000     Source: Process Cube Dimensions Analysis Services Execute DDL Task     Description: The following system error occurred:  A device attached to the system is not functioning.   End Error  Error: 2023-04-12 12:33:10.34     Code: 0xC1010000     Source: Process Cube Dimensions Analysis Services Execute DDL Task     Description: The following system error occurred:  A device attached to the system is not functioning.   End Error  Error: 2023-04-12 12:33:10.35     Code: 0xC1010000     Source: Process Cube Dimensions Analysis Services Execute DDL Task     Description: The following system error occurred:  A device attached to the system is not functioning.   End Error  Error: 2023-04-12 12:33:10.35     Code: 0xC1010000     Source: Process Cube Dimensions Analysis Services Execute DDL Task     Description: The following system error occurred:  A device attached to the system is not functioning.   End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  12:33:08 pm  Finished: 12:33:10 pm  Elapsed:  1.672 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.*